# What is tensorflow.compat.as_str()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the [Google/Udemy Tensorflow tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb) there is the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
...
def read_data(filename):
    """Extract the first file enclosed in a zip file as a list of words"""
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as f:
    data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read(f.namelist()[0])).split()
return data
```

This executes fine but I cannot find `compat.as_str` in the Tensorflow documentation or anywhere else.

Q1: What does `compat.as_str` do?

Q2: Is this tensorflow `compat` library documented somewhere?

Q3: This is a call to the tensorflow library, so how and why does it work in normal python code, rather than inside a tensorflow graph? I.e. I thought tensorflow library calls had to be inside a tensorflow graph defintion block:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default()
    ... tensorflow function calls here ...
```

I am running python 2.7.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, it comes from the fact that in Python 2, strings were dealt with primarily as bytes, not unicode.
In Python 3, all strings are natively unicode.
The purpose of the function is to ensure that whichever Python version you're using, you won't be bothered, hence the `compat` module name standing for compatibility.

Under the hood, `tensorflow.compat.as_str` converts both `bytes` and `unicode` strings to `unicode` strings.

```
Signature: tensorflow.compat.as_str(bytes_or_text, encoding='utf-8')
Docstring:
Returns the given argument as a unicode string.

Args:
  bytes_or_text: A `bytes`, `str, or `unicode` object.
  encoding: A string indicating the charset for decoding unicode.

Returns:
  A `unicode` (Python 2) or `str` (Python 3) object.

Raises:
  TypeError: If `bytes_or_text` is not a binary or unicode string.
```

The library is documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat).

Answer (score 8):

1. `tf.compat.as_str` converts input into a string
2. I couldn't find any documentation, but you can look at the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py)
3. Tensorflow functions as a python module. The [graph context](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/framework.html#core-graph-data-structures) is used to define a graph (mathematical computations) that will be used to train the model.

> typical usage involves the Graph.as_default() context manager, which overrides the current default graph for the lifetime of the contex

Answer (score 3):

In a current version of TF, the whole [`tf.compat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat) group is nicely documented.

Basically some things behaves differently in python 2 and 3 (might be slightly inaccurate, python gurus can help me with this). Python3 uses 64-bit floats and python2 32-bit floats, there are also difference with respect to [strings](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#unicode). Compat module tries things to behave in the same way (if you will check the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py) you will see that they do different things depending on whether you use 2 or 3).

---

[`tf.compat.as_str`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/as_bytes#tfcompatas_str):

> Converts either bytes or unicode to bytes, using utf-8 encoding for
>   text.

This can be helpful if you save the data in tfrecords and want to make sure it will be saved in the same way no matter which python version is used.

Comment: I suspect there is a mistake in the documentation, as the output of `tf.compat.as_str` is always a `unicode` string, not a `bytes` one